# Change SMTP user according to the user in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I want to assign different SMTP hosts to different authenticated users so that the privileged users can send mails faster through a dedicated SMTP server.

I can change the host in the service provider like:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->extend('swift.transport', function ($transportManager, $app) {
           $app->make('config')->set('mail.host', 'just.testing.com');
           return new TransportManager($app);
        });
    }
}
```

However since I need the authenticated user I created a listener listening to "Authenticated" event and moved the code there like:

```
class ChangeSmtpServer
{
    public function handle($event)
    {
        app()->extend('swift.transport', function ($transportManager, $app) use ($event) {
            $app->make('config')->set('mail.host', $event->user->smtp_server);
            return new TransportManager($app);
        });
    }
}
```

The host is not changed this time... So inside the service provider I can overwrite the setting but not inside the listener.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works on my setup just fine. Actually it should still work if you keep it in AppServiceProvider because Laravel will only resolve bindings when they are relevant. So the code pertaining to Mail driver configuration will not be run until you actually try to send a Mail. By that point your user will already be authenticated. However...

This will only work when you send your mail synchronously. When you want to send from a Queue worker, there won't be any authenticated user and the Authenticated event will never be called. You need a way to keep track of which user is sending the e-mail.

Here is my solution:

Add a sender argument to your Mail class constructor (the one in App\Mail) that takes in the User object that's sending the e-mail.

```
public $sender;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(User $sender)
{
    $this->sender = $sender;
}
```

Then add this method that configures your SwiftMailer instance

```
private function usingSendersSmtp()
{
    $mailTransport = app()->make('mailer')
        ->getSwiftMailer()
        ->getTransport();

    if ($mailTransport instanceof \Swift_SmtpTransport) {
        /** @var \Swift_SmtpTransport $mailTransport */
        $mailTransport->setHost($this->sender->smtp_host);
        $mailTransport->setUsername($this->sender->smtp_username);
        $mailTransport->setPassword($this->sender->smtp_password);
        // Port and authentication can also be configured... You get the picture
    }

    return $this;
}
```

And finally call it inside your build method:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->usingSendersSmtp()
        ->view('test');
}
```

When sending the mail, instantiate your class like `new YourMailClass(auth()->user())` and then send it or queue it with the Mail facade to whomever you like. It also might be a good idea to create an abstract class that inherits Illuminate\Mail\Mailable and move these extra stuff over there so you won't have to duplicate this in every other mail class. Hope this helps!